# Is there a way around "Error: Command Line Too long"?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, bash, error

I am using a command line software for which I need to input a lot of arguments. Something like

```
./exec -A argA -B argB -C argC ...
```

There are so many arguments that I get the error message

```
Error: Command line too long (302110 >= 130592)
```

One solution would be to modify the software so that it reads arguments from a file. However, I don't have access to the source code.

Is there a way around this problem?

---

FYI, I am on `Mac OS X 10.11.3` and use `Terminal 2.6.1 (361.1)`

Comment: `getconf ARG_MAX` -the maximum characters allowed by the kernel.

Comment: interestingly `getconf ARG_MAX` returns `262144` which is almost twice as much as `130592` (but still lower than `302110 `).

Answer (score 3):

Put the arguments in a file such as `-A argA -B argB -C argC …` (excluding the binary), then run:

```
cat /path/to/file | xargs ./exec
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I had some trouble while investigating the application of your solution to my specific issue (even though that sounds super simple) and so I asked [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39648748/how-can-i-feed-this-long-line-of-arguments-to-an-executable?noredirect=1#comment66601135_39648748) where the first answer seems to say that `cat /path/to/file | xargs ./exec` cannot be a solution anyway.